# Unexpected results while fetching the total number of followers of a user on twitter

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

When I run it, the terminal keeps tying "23851" in new rows, which is the number of followers of the first Twitter name in my file f; I believe this means that the pointer was not moving in file f, but I'm not sure how this should be done properly in Python 2) when I check my file f1, there's nothing, i.e. the program is not writing to f1 as expected.

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
CONSUMER_KEY = 'xxx'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'xxx'
ACCESS_KEY = 'xxx'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'xxx'
auth = OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)

#Create Class First
class TweetListener(StreamListener):
# A listener handles tweets are the received from the stream.
#This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to standard output
def on_data(self, data): # indented inside the class
    print(data)
    return True

def on_error(self, status):
    print(status)

# open both files outside the loop

with open('Twitternames.txt') as f,open('followers_number.txt', 'a') as f1:
    for x in f:   
        #search
        api = tweepy.API(auth)
        twitterStream = Stream(auth,TweetListener())
        test = api.lookup_users(screen_names=['x'])
    for user in test:
            print(user.followers_count)
            #print it out and also write it into a file
            s = user.followers_count
            f1.write(str(s) +"\n") # add a newline with +        
#end of stackoverflow        
f.close()
```

Comment: Can you format your code correctly?

Comment: Yea
Sorry about that

Comment: To second what @PaulRooney said, as written, "test" is not defined. Please format the code so it runs.

Comment: @Lequnia you should change your API keys on Twitter.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are some things to consider, There are some unwanted lines as well. So I will go line by line and explain the relevant things ,as we don't need any streaming data for counting the number of follower , so we need to import only tweepy and OauthHandler, so :

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
```

Now we need to set the 4 keys required for login so, This will go same as :

```
CONSUMER_KEY = 'xxxxxxxx' #Replace with the original values.
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'xxx'   #Replace with the original values.
ACCESS_KEY = 'xxx'        #Replace with the original values.
ACCESS_SECRET = 'xxx'     #Replace with the original values.

auth = OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
```

I don't guess you would need, StreamListner to just log the follower_count of various users. So I am skipping that part, However you can add that code snippet afterwards.

```
usernames_file = open('Twitternames.txt').readlines()
```

I am assuming the contents of `Twitternames.txt` to be in the following format(every username without `@` symbol and separated by a new line):

```
user_name_1
user_name_2
user_name_3
...
```

now the usernames_file would be list of strings `usernames_file= ['user_name_1\n', 'user_name_2\n', 'user_name_3\n']` so now we have extracted the various usernames from the text file, but we need to get rid of that `\n` character at the end of each name. So we can use `.strip()` method.

```
usernames = []
for i in usernames_file:
    usernames.append(i.strip())

>>> usernames = ['user_name_1', 'user_name_2', 'user_name_3']
```

Now we are ready to use the lookup_users method as this method takes a list of usernames as input.

So it may look something like this:

```
test = api.lookup_users(screen_names=usernames)
for user in test:
    print(user.followers_count)
```

If you want to log the results to a `.txt` file then you can use:

```
log_file = open("log.txt", 'a')
test = api.lookup_users(screen_names=usernames)
for user in test:
    print(user.followers_count)
    log_file.write(user.name+" has "+str(user.followers_count)+" followers.\n")
log_file.close()
```

So the short and final code would look something like this:

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler

CONSUMER_KEY = 'xxx'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'xxx'
ACCESS_KEY = 'xxx'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'xxx'

auth = OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

usernames_file = open('Twitternames.txt').readlines()

usernames = []
for i in usernames_file:
    usernames.append(i.strip())

log_file = open("log.txt", 'a')
test = api.lookup_users(screen_names=usernames)
for user in test:
    print(user.followers_count)
    log_file.write(user.name+" has "+str(user.followers_count)+" followers.\n")
log_file.close()
```